# Prevent session timeout from resetting for periodical ajax calls

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1, .net-core-2.1

In my ASP.NET MVC application there is a periodical ajax call to fetch new notifications for the current user. However this call resets the idle timeout for the current session, causing the session to never expire. This is a security risk. How can I prevent certain endpoint calls from resetting the idle timeout?

Comment: Are you talking about legacy .Net Framework or about .net core / .net 5? They have absolutely different approach for working with sessions.

Comment: Hi Alexey, I am using .NET Core 2.1 (tag added)

Answer (score 1):

Session state in ASP NET Core is maintained by `SessionMiddleware`, it is design is pretty simple. I will omit starting part where session is loaded, you are interested in this part where next middleware calls are wrapped in such way.

```
try
{
    await _next(context); //Here are all other middlewares executed
}
finally
{
    context.Features.Set<ISessionFeature>(null);

    if (feature.Session != null)
    {
        try
        {
            await feature.Session.CommitAsync(); //Here your session is commited and prolongated
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            _logger.SessionCommitCanceled();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.ErrorClosingTheSession(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

So if you are accessing session read-only you can just not commit it when you are hitting your periodical endpoint, you can figure it out from `HttpContext context`. If you prevent block of code that commits session from execution it will not put new entry in `IDistributedCache` renewing it's sliding expiration and session will remain unaltered.

You also have to write analogue of `SessionMiddlewareExtensions` class where `UseSession` extension method is defined and provide your own implementation registering your custom middleware.

Comment: Thank you Alexey, I will try to implement it.